# Install graphicsmagik and ffmpeg for nodeJS application running as docker container

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, docker, ffmpeg, graphicsmagick

I am deploying a nodeJS application (which is based on meteorJS and build with `meteor build`) to a docker container on my ubuntu 16.04 server.
My application needs `graphicsmagick` and `ffmpeg`.
As far as I know, the `ffmpeg` should be in the `libav-tools` package.

My question is how do I get those two needed packages into my application running as docker container?

I think it is wrong to install them via `apt-get graphicsmagick` on the server itself, right?

For this nodeJS application I'm using this Dockerfile to create a docker image:

```
FROM node:4.8-slim

# Copy the application files
COPY . /

# Set required environment variables
ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV MONGO_URL mongodb://mongo:27017/
ENV ROOT_URL http://localhost
ENV PORT 80
EXPOSE 80

# Download the required packages for production
RUN (cd programs/server && npm install --silent)

# Make the application run when running the container
CMD ["node", "main.js"]
```

My application uses this package.json:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "ffmpeg": "0.0.4",
    "fluent-ffmpeg": "^2.1.2",
    "gm": "^1.23.0",
    ...
  }
}
```

Running `npm install` should add `gm` and `ffmpeg`, but I think I need those packages installed in the docker container itself.

Comment: Try adding `RUN apt-add-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media -y && apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y graphicsmagick ffmpeg` to your docker file and see if it helps

Comment: I do get the error `/bin/sh: 1: apt-add-repository: not found`. Is it a problem, that the Dockerfile base image is `node`?

Comment: Add `apt-get install -y python-software-properties && ` at the start of the command i gave earlier

Comment: Using `software-properties-common` instead of `python-software-properties` and `libav-tools` instead of `ffmpeg` is working. Thanks for your help

Comment: Only for my understanding: Why do I have to use `ppa:mc3man/trusty-media`? Why is `apt-get install -y graphicsmagick` not sufficient by itself?

Comment: When you do `apt-get install xyz`. Package name is `xyz`and it is search in the default repositories available on the system. But some packages is not available in the default distro. So you add external channels which publish those packages. So that is the reason we use `mc3man/trusty-media` which provides the packages